# What column type should be used to store serialized data in a postgresql 9.2 db?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, crontrigger

Previously i was using the BLOB data type in oracle to store a serialized data of quartz(job data) and it was working correct but right now i am using POSTGRESQL 9.2 so i would like to know that which data type is best for the same. And also i  am using hibernate so what extra changes required to work it correctly. I tried bytea but getting error:Unexpected scheduling error when executing. Error : Couldn't store job: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(1). So could you please help me as i am trying it from previous 4 days but got nothing. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the type is really BYTEA? Looks like something thinks it's a VARCHAR(1). Alternately, some other field is and won't fit the value you set for that.

Comment: Hi Joachim, thank you so much to you, actually i changed data type ranges of all the table names start with qrtz_% to 250. and it started working. But can you please tell me that which data type is best for stroing serialized data in postgresql?

Comment: `BYTEA` is the only binary string type I know of, so as long as your serialization generates a binary, it seems like a good match.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson In order for other people to see that the question has been answered please consider adding an answer.

Comment: @ArtemGr My expertise isn't really PostgreSQL and/or hibernate, so I'll defer the answer to someone who doesn't have to add so many "Looks like" and "I know of" :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's right, use [BYTEA](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-binary.html). Large values will be stored externally, see [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html).